# How to reach the max number from two lists

Tags: java

I have two arraylists , I store in them random numbers .. then I calculate the max number of first list (player1) and second list (player2) ...
The problem that I can not reach the max number of player1 and player2 , as you can see , the code compare `int max1 = Integer.MIN_VALUE;` with `int max2 = Integer.MIN_VALUE;` .. so the output is always `tie`
In my code I did calculate the max number of player1 and player2 but I can not reach them ..
How can I reach the max number player1 to compare it with max number from player2 ?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;


public class Main {

    int static maximum(ArrayList A){
        int max=0;
        for(int s=0; s<A.size(); s++){
            if(A.get(s)>max){
                max=A.get(s);
            }
        }
        return max;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<Integer> player1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> player2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        int max1=maximum(player1);
        int max2=maximum(player2);
        Random rn = new Random();

        for (int i=0; i<=5; i++){
        int value1 = rn.nextInt(13)+1;
        player1.add(value1);
        } 
        System.out.println(player1);

        for (int i=0; i<=5; i++){
        int value2 = rn.nextInt(13)+1;
        player2.add(value2);
        }
        System.out.println(player2);

        if(max1>max2){
            System.out.println("player1 is winner");

        } else if (max1<max2){
            System.out.println("player2 is winner");
        } else {
        System.out.println("tie");
                        }

                        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you should check for player two here, not player one. 
Here is what you did:

```
 int max2 = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for(int s=0; s<player1.size(); s++){
        if(player1.get(s)>max2){
            max2=player1.get(s);
        }
    }
```

and the correct one should be :

```
 int max2 = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for(int s=0; s<player2.size(); s++){
        if(player2.get(s)>max2){
            max2=player2.get(s);
        }
    }
```

> EDIT:

You can just call from your main() :

```
max1 = maximum(player1);
max2 = maximum(player2);

int maximum(ArrayList A)
{
int max = 0;
    for(int s=0; s<A.size(); s++){
        if(A.get(s)>max){
            max=A.get(s);
        }
   } 
return max;
 }
```

And then just compare the max1 and max2 as you are doing.

> EDIT 2 :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;


public class Main {

int static maximum(ArrayList A){
    int max=0;
    for(int s=0; s<A.size(); s++){
        if(A.get(s)>max){
            max=A.get(s);
        }
    }
    return max;
}


public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<Integer> player1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> player2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();


    Random rn = new Random();

    for (int i=0; i<=5; i++){
    int value1 = rn.nextInt(13)+1;
    player1.add(value1);
    } 
    System.out.println(player1);

    for (int i=0; i<=5; i++){
    int value2 = rn.nextInt(13)+1;
    player2.add(value2);
    }
    System.out.println(player2);
    int max1=maximum(player1);
    int max2=maximum(player2);

    if(max1>max2){
        System.out.println("player1 is winner");

    } else if (max1<max2){
        System.out.println("player2 is winner");
    } else {
    System.out.println("tie");
                    }

                    }
     }
```

Comment: I corrected it ...but as I said that the code compare int max1 = Integer.MIN_VALUE; with int max2 = Integer.MIN_VALUE; .. so the output is always tie .. WHAT TO DO ? THANKS

Comment: How about if you initialize max1 and max2 = 0  instead of Integer.MIN_VALUE ?

Comment: No worries, you can accept the answer if it works for you!

Comment: There's still a bug somewhere in the code using `MIN_VALUE` should work.  make sure the other player is the winner sometimes too.  I'm guessing your code is still not working properly

Comment: iT WORKED NOW BROTHER ... THANK YOU ... IF I WANT TO MAKE SUB CLASS FOR BOTH MAX1 AND MAX2 CAN YOU SHOW ME HOW TO DO IT?? I WILL ACCEPT YOUR ANSWER , I HAVE TO WAIT A WHILE TO ACCEPT

Comment: Why do you need subclass for max1 and max2?

Comment: I want to learn myself to do subclass ... I want the main method shorter than what I have above?? thank you

Comment: How about methods? creating a single method can calculate maximum for both of the players and then you can compare accordingly.

Comment: Ok I put max1 = maximum(player1);
max2 = maximum(player2); in main and created the subclass you mentioned but I am getting error ,,check my code above

Comment: This is not a subclass, It is a method which you can declare outside the main() method in the same class.
For subclass, you need perform inheritance.

Comment: No , I have error here ;  max1=maximum(player1);
  max2=maximum(player2); it says Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method maximum(ArrayList) from the 
  type Main
 - max1 cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: Ok so there are more than one error here: 1> You have to define max1 and max2, what are they? they are int right. so make them int max1 and int max2.  2> you have to call the maximum() method after filling the arraylist, so place both of these lines after filling the values in the arraylist.

3> make the maximum method as static, because you are referencing this method from a static method.

Answer (score 1):

You have a copy and paste mistake in your 2nd for loop.

```
int max2 = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for(int s=0; s<player1.size(); s++){
        if(player1.get(s)>max2){
            max2=player1.get(s);
        }
    }
```

should be for `player2`.  but because you are iterating over `player1` again both max1 and max2 are the same value.

Comment: I corrected it ...but as I said that the code compare int max1 = Integer.MIN_VALUE; with int max2 = Integer.MIN_VALUE; .. so the output is always tie .. WHAT TO DO ? THANKS

Comment: can you post your updated code?  and example print out of `player1` and `player2` ? you probably have another bug

Comment: iT WORKED NOW BROTHER ... THANK YOU ... IF I WANT TO MAKE SUB CLASS FOR BOTH MAX1 AND MAX2 CAN YOU SHOW ME HOW TO DO IT??

Answer (score 0):

Write less !, there are a lot of Java functionallity that is there but We don't know because of that we push ot ourserlves to write innecesary (sometimes even inneficient code).

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        //You fill it with random numbers
        Integer player1A[] = {1,2,3,4, 10};
        Integer player2A[] = {5,6,3,10};

        List<Integer> player1 = Arrays.asList(player1A);
        List<Integer> player2 = Arrays.asList(player2A);

        Integer maxPlayer1 = Collections.max(player1);
        Integer maxPlayer2 = Collections.max(player2);

        System.out.println("Max Player 1 = " + maxPlayer1);
        System.out.println("Max Player 2 = " + maxPlayer2);

        if(maxPlayer1 > maxPlayer2) {
            System.out.println("Win player 1");
        } else if(maxPlayer2 > maxPlayer1) {            
            System.out.println("Win player 2");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Draw");
        }
    }
```

Comment: THANK YOU ... IF I WANT TO MAKE SUB CLASS FOR BOTH MAX1 AND MAX2 CAN YOU SHOW ME HOW TO DO IT BY USING MY CODE ABOVE??

Comment: Do you mean? public static Integer getMax(List<Integer> list) {
        return Collections.max(list);
    }

Comment: yes .. how to call this subclass in my main method??

Comment: Just declare the method in the Main class and call it in this way getMax(player1);